# Excel filter to include blanks

Tags: excel, filtering, vba

I have this excel sheet and I need to have a filter on one of the columns. The thing is that the row which is just below the title column is empty and in order to include that row i have to filter by both VALUE and BLANK.

Is it possible to filter just by a value and still have this row to appear :? 
The users of this excel file would find it easily if this can be done. They dont fancy applying custom filtering.

I am open to any suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: is there a _Dumb Question_ hat? I may get one for this but:- Why is there an empty row between the titles and data?

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald is totally right. The _best_ solution would be to get rid of the blank row.

Comment: Is this a formatting thing? If it is, you could make your first row twice as big and vertically align all the text towards the top of the row. You would get a pretty close effect to looking like you had a blank row in between the headers and the data.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create a marco with adding a custom filter (hide the blank row) and add the macro to a button or icon.